# Is asking a similar question but without irrelevant context OK?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

I am wondering if it is alright to re-ask a question if you can only find context-specific questions that use methods that can solve your problem but is not your specific problem (probably most relevant to Stack Overflow).

My arguments for doing this are:

1. When people search for a solution they do not want to wade through irrelevant detail that does not apply to their problem in the question (and as a result quite often in the answer) and stops bifurcation like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/is-asking-a-question-that-duplicates-the-topic-of-previous-question-but-seeks-a);
2. The extra context can in fact be too specific and may not actually yield a solution, thus resulting in uncertainty when trying a number of different solutions;
3. It will ultimately simplify and streamline the searching for answers for other people as key-words in the search will be focused on a universal question, not just the solution of one person;
4. It is more likely to result in a strategy change for the particular problem rather than the actual answer as noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/asking-similar-questions-process)

I hope that the Stack Exchanges can implement something like [this concept of making questions canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote); perhaps this should also emphasise the universality of the solution

EDIT: TL;DR Can you re-ask a question but without less situation-dependent content to refine the answer to something which applies to more situations?

Comment: This is a great example of the time wasting that specific answers create: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387985/type-mismatch-error-excel-vba-looping-through-each-column-of-used-range

Comment: Not that there is an issue with the above answer for the user but it adds no value to additional users seeking an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically I would say that if you are asking a question with different or minimal context it is in fact a different question.

From what you are saying it seems like you dislike filtering through lines of code-text to get an answer which may not apply to your situation.

Removing said code and asking the question directly is strictly a different question; albeit solved by a similar solution though.

Ask away.

P.S. Stack Overflow has started documentation which will hopefully solve this issue of making answers more "canonical".