# Is the full bounty awarded if an answer is accepted after half the bounty is awarded?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

If half the bounty is awarded to the top voted answer, and that answer is accepted later, will the other half of the bounty be awarded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't. Once the bounty is awarded automatically, its amount (half the bounty investment) is locked in and won't change, even if the question author (and I presume the bounty giver) later accepts the answer.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283220/295232) is an example from 2016: a 50-reputation bounty was posted by the question owner, but only half of it was awarded on August 23rd. The answer was accepted on September 2nd, but that only gave the author +15, not the remaining 25 points of the bounty, as can be seen in their [reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/338597/glyphd?tab=reputation).